# How may I restrict uploads to a single folder with variables within a Rich Text Field?

Tags: assets, redactor, richtext, variable, upload

Craft's Asset Fields allow you to restrict uploads to a single folder—and even pass through a variable to create a dynamic path. How may I restrict uploads to a single folder with variables like this within Craft's Rich Text Field?

I would like to collect images added within the Redactor-powered editor within folders that are unique to each entry within Craft.